# Porque não consigo lidar com erros ao mapear tabelas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, oracle12c

Como posso melhorar a manipulação de erros ao mapear tabelas/views?
Já resolvi o erro, porém preciso enviar por e-mail uma mensagem com detalhes do erro, como não é Code First, acabo tendo esses erros direto, pois somos 3 desenvolvedores.

Já tenho uma função de envio de e-mail, mas não sei como inserir um try/catch ou algo assim antes de mapear as tabelas, podem me ajudar a tratar esses erros de mapeamento? Nos momentos de gravação e etc eu consigo naturalmente tratar isso, mas ao mapear essas views/tabelas não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso abaixo é uma view, e nela tinha um erro bobo que já acertei, levei um hora pra identificar que estava escrito **CODIDO** ao invés de **CODIGO** (que é o correto):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FichaInscricao.Domain;

namespace Fgv.FichaInscricao.Repository.Map
{
    public class AreaFuncionalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AreaFuncional>
    {
        public AreaFuncionalMap()
        {
            ToTable("N_AREA_FUNCIONAL");
            HasKey(x => new { x.Codigo, x.CulturaSigla });
            Property(x => x.Codigo).HasColumnName("CODIDO");
            Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("NOME");
            Property(x => x.CulturaSigla).HasColumnName("CULTURA");
        }
    }
}
```

Estou usando essas configurações:

- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2
- Oracle 12c

Comment: Por que você não consegue inserir o try catch?

Comment: Estranho, estava dando erro, agora funcionou! Obrigado @LeandroAngelo !